# Making an accordion from a multi-level HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing some code to turn a multi level UL into an accordion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.s4-ql li ul').each(function (index) {
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.s4-ql ul li ul').each(function (index) {
    var length = 0;
    length = $(this).children().length;
    var CurrentItem = $(this).parent().find('a:first');
    CurrentItem.find('.menu-item-text').append('<span style=\'float:right;font-size:0.8em;\'>(' + length + ')</span>');
});
$('.s4-ql ul li').hover(
  function () {
      $(this).find('a:first').next().slideToggle('normal');
  },
  function () {
      $(this).find('a:first').next().slideToggle('normal');
  }
);
});
```

Can anyone tell me whether I am being relatively efficient or whether there is anywhere that I can "trim the fat", so to speak? The code also counts the number of children and displays that number on the main parent.

Comment: Also, speaking of "trimming the fat", please don't write tags in titles and signatures in questions.

Comment: What do you mean Tom?  sorry? - As for code review..thx for that link, was not aware of it.

Comment: @user257503: I mean, please don't write tags in titles (like "jQuery: "), and signatures/thanks are not required (and will be edited out) as you're writing a question not an email! ta [not the same for comments :P]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be good if you can provide your HTML markup. Without it I can do this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.s4-ql li ul').hide();
    $('.s4-ql ul li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').next().slideToggle();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('a:first').next().slideToggle();
    }).find('ul').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().find('a:first .menu-item-text').append(['<span style=\'float:right;font-size:0.8em;\'>(', $this.children().length, ')</span>'].join(''));
    });;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery mutation methods operate on every element in the set.
You can just write `$('.s4-ql li ul').hide()`; you don't need `.each`.

Also, you should just write `var length = $(this).children().length;` in one line.